# Update field values based on picklist change

Tags: formula, process-builder, field-update

I am trying to achieve the following functionality using process builder but I am not getting it exactly what I need:

I have one custom field in opportunity called `order(Text)` and standard field `Stage` Now, I need to populate the number in `order(Text)` when `stage` is changed to `closed/won` and this need to be work for each opportunity which has the `stage` value `closed/won`.

I know we can achieve this by writing `Apex Trigger`, but here I have `Professional Edition` and I can not write any trigger or Workflow. So, at least I have a choice to create process builder and achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this by creating another `Custom Object`, custom `AutoNumber` field in `Custom Object` and another process builder,

1. I created One Process builder on Opportunity:

   **Criteria:** `Opp.Stage == 'Closed/Won' && opp.Stage ISCHANGED == True`

   **Action:** create a record of that custom object (work order) (when the record will create the `AutoNumber` field will populate automatically)
2. I created another Process builder on the custom object (work order)

   **Criteria:** `work_Order__c.AutoNumber != Null`

   **Action:** Update the `Opportunity` and update the field `Work_Order__c` (Assign the custom object(work Order) field `AutoNumber` to Opportunity's custom field `Work_Order__c`)

Comment: So you will have a corresponding record for every time an opportunity is closed/won. Good that you found an alternative being in a Professional Edition.

Answer (score -1):

Try the below Process Builder.It is working according your requirement.
[image]

[image]

[image]

I hope it will help you.
Regards,
Akshay

Comment: Hi, Can you please read this : You have a field in Opportunity, order. When OpportunityOne is updated to Closed/Won, the order field of OpportunityOne is changed to 1. Now, say OpportunityTwo is updated to Closed/Won, order field of OpportunityTwo is changed to 2

Comment: @WantToBeACoder
On a opportunity standard object , we can not create process builder according your requirement .I think , It could be happen through a  custom object. Then we can update Order(text) field of opportunity .